# Grub Not Showing

Tags: grub2

I have HP G6-2312AX laptop with windows 8 pre-installed, 
I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS successfully but after completing the setup I was asked to restart the system. After restarting it is loading Windows directly. How should I install GRUB? or is there any other way through which I can choose which OS is to be load?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the ubuntu grub? If yes, press <kbd>left shift</kbd> while restarting. Try tapping it, and if that doesn't work, try pressing it until the grub appears.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Windows Boot Manager Sucks..

I prefer you to use Ubuntu Grub Menu, that is let Ubuntu to allow you to chose which OS you want to boot (Windows or Ubuntu).

Here are the steps that would help you..

Boot from your Ubuntu LiveCD/DVD or Ubuntu bootable USB and select 'Try Ubuntu' (not 'Install Ubuntu'). When Ubuntu starts open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

Installing boot-repair ( a good s/w to fix grub ):

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install boot-repair
    Run boot-repair from your system or type: (boot-repair &) in terminal
```

When started select Option 'Recommended Repair' from out of two options:

'Recommended Repair' & 'Advanced Options'.

Follow very easy onscreen instruction, it will build/fix your grub menu..

Restarting your system may list all the Operating Systems installed in your HDD.
Be sure that you have properly shut down Windows 8, before starting these steps..

You can get more help on - [Using Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)